# how to add a rightbarbuttonitem in specific view of tabbarcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

as my title, how do i add in a rightbarbuttontiem in a specific view of tabbarcontroller ?

i'm using storyboard to create the tabarcontroller.

i tried this but the item are not displayed

```
   UIBarButtonItem *settingButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]  
                                  initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gear.png"]  
                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain  
                                  target:self  
                                  action:@selector(pushToSetting)];  

//BarButtonItem *settingButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = settingButton;
```

Comment: you are mixing up UITabBarController and UINavigationController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a NavigationController? If you are, then your code should work. If you are using just a UINavigationBar, then you have to set the items property for the UINavigationBar. As you are not getting a rightbuttonitem, I assume you are using a UINavigationBar. This code should work:

```
UIBarButtonItem *settingButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Settings" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil];
UINavigationItem *navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test"];
navItem.rightBarButtonItem = settingButton;
NSArray *navItems = [NSArray arrayWithObject:navItem];
[self.navBar setItems:navItems];
```

You should have the rightbarbuttonitem now. Here, navBar is a UINavigationBar outlet. You can also pop and push navigation items onto a UINavigationBar using these methods:

- (void)pushNavigationItem:(UINavigationItem *)item animated:(BOOL)animated;
- (UINavigationItem *)popNavigationItemAnimated:(BOOL)animated;